# What does -Werror do in the Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

At university we are taught to compile our projects using:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -ansi -o myfile.out myfile.c -lm
```

However, I can't seem to find an explanation online of what '`Werror`' does?

Comment: Did you try `man gcc` to see what its options do? Isn't that how you find out what command options mean for any command?

Comment: The title of your question suggests a severe misunderstanding about how command options work. There's no general meaning to any options, they're defined by the specific command.

Comment: No I didn't because I wasn't aware that existed. You'd be correct in assuming I have a severe misunderstanding but thankfully you're here to correct me! @Barmar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It reports all warnings as errors so the compilation stops without proceeding. Otherwise only warnings will be shown on console with `-Wall` but compilation doesn't stop. If you want to read about it, head to [gnu page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

```
-Werror

    Make all warnings into errors.
```

Here is an example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("%s\n", "Good");
    return 0;
}
```

When you pass `-Werror`

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -ansi abc.c
abc.c: In function ‘main’:
abc.c:5:9: error: unused variable ‘i’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
     int i;
         ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Without `-Werror` it will compile as well as run.

```
$ gcc -Wall  -ansi abc.c
abc.c: In function ‘main’:
abc.c:5:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int i;
         ^

$ ./a.out 
Good
```